# Exporting Dynamic@Graphic with Mathematica and Player Pro

Tags: graphics, dynamic, wolfram-player

Why does

```
DynamicModule[{grf, x}, 
 Panel[{Button["Export", Export["test.png", grf]], 
   Slider[Dynamic[x], {1, 4}], 
   grf = Dynamic[Graphics[{Line[{{1, x}, {x, 1}, {3, 2}}]}]]}]]
```

export properly in *Mathematica* but not in Player Pro, while

```
DynamicModule[{grf, x}, 
 Panel[{Button["Export", Export["test.png", grf]], 
   Slider[Dynamic[x], {1, 4}], 
   Dynamic[grf = Graphics[{Line[{{1, x}, {x, 1}, {3, 2}}]}]]}]]
```

exports properly in both?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot tell you, why *Mathematica* can handle your first case properly, while the Player doesn't, but I can tell you why your first example is wrong. Writing something like

```
grf = Dynamic[Graphics[....
```

is a bad idea, because, although you don't see it, the `Dynamic` head is still there. You can observe this by changing your example slightly

```
DynamicModule[{grf, x}, 
 Panel[{Button["Export", Print[InputForm[grf]]], 
   Slider[Dynamic[x], {1, 4}], 
   grf = Dynamic[Graphics[{Line[{{1, x}, {x, 1}, {3, 2}}]}]]}]]
```

When you now hit the button, then you see that you don't have a `Graphics`, you have a `Graphics` wraped in `Dynamic`. I guess the player cannot handle this.

You second example is correct, because you *dynamicly set `grf`* by wrapping the complete expression. Use the same print and you see that `Export` will get a correct `Graphics` object.